# Magento 2.3.0 - Can't login to admin

Tags: magento2, php, admin, login, magento2.3

I can't login to admin panel on Magento 2.3.0 version. After I press **Sign In** button I have this message: "***Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.***"
and in the system.log file I have this:

```
[2019-02-15 12:32:34] main.ERROR: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. [] []
[2019-02-15 12:32:34] main.CRITICAL: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. [] []
```

In the browser console I see this:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://www.domain.com/pub/static/version1550234757/adminhtml/Magento/backend/pt_PT/js-translation.json"
js-tran...on.json
Error: https://www.domain.com/pub/static/version1550234757/adminhtml/Magento/backend/pt_PT/js-translation.json HTTP status: 404


err = new Error(url + ' HTTP status: ' + status);
```

Comment: are you on localhost?

Comment: @magefms no, I use a server, this problem I think appear after I use Migration Tool to import data

Comment: yeah, that could be one reason

Comment: @magefms please check I just edit my question, I found this in the browser console

Comment: which command did you run ? have you tried redeploying static-content?

Comment: have you done migration from magento 1 to magento 2 ?

Comment: @magefms I use this: php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli indeed, I migrate only the data from Magento 1 to Magento 2.3.0

Comment: check this: 
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you migrated from Magento 1 to Magento 2.3 , the data. I would suggest some reasons that may help you fix the issue :

1. Upgrade your `password_hash` using **md5()** to **sha256()**

   php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade.
2. Remove `var/migration-tool-progress.lock`
3. Replace the `crypt key` with the one of magento 1 key .
4. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Vendor/Theme en_US pt_PT -f`
5. You havent migrated the store [Link](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/630)

Comment: thank you, if I use this command php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade I have the following error
Notice: Undefined index: 0:1 in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdo
  cs/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 189

Comment: Need more info for that error, anyway you can skip that and try the others , deploying content based on the theme php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Vendor/Theme en_US -f

Comment: I already do the deploy of the content without any success

Comment: Try tu run the content deploy like this : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US pt_PT -f

Comment: I just enable the developer mode is the same, I run this command too and when is run from ssh it appear this text "The store that was requested wasn't found."  with red color.

Comment: But are you using this store pt_PT ?

Comment: yes, is just the normal store but translated

Comment: I use this command: php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/backend pt_PT -f and I have this error message in ssh : The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.

Comment: That means you havent migrated the store https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/630

Comment: I migrate only the data I don't migrate the settings