# magento2 Invalid Form Key on chrome

Tags: magento2, form-key

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page?

My chrome browser always give this error even if I have changed the `php.ini` 
configuration

```
max_input_vars = 75000
```

I am using **nginx server** and public IP (hosted the site in public server).
in Firefox it works very well.

Comment: have you check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261995/magento-2-3-0-cant-login-to-admin

Comment: @dhananjay have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You already set your `max_input_vars` to `100000` and it worked on firefox

This is usually to do with the cookie domain setting being wrongly set in your Magento set up. So...

1) Make sure the cookie domain is set to the correct domain in core_config_data

2) Clear the cache

3) Finally, delete all Local Storage, Session Storage and Cookies for the new domain in browser. If you're using Chrome, just right-click, Inspect and go to the "Application" tab and clear those areas.

Comment: I have stage.maindomain.com and cookie domain value I have set is maindomain.com I have also tried .maindomain.com but still facing issue. Is there anything else that can be done.